# Continuity of a function on $\ell^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces

I want to prove the set $c_{0}$ is closed in $\ell^{\infty}$. But I saw what could be done with the following function: $f: \ell^\infty \to \mathbb{R} $ defined by $x \mapsto \limsup_n | x_n | $. But I can't prove that $f$ is continuous. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: So you need to show that the function $(x_n)\mapsto\limsup_n|x_n|$ is continuous in order to prove that $c_0$ is closed in $\ell^\infty$ (by saying that $c_0$ is the set $f^{-1}(0)$ whic is closed by continuity I guess). Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Yes. I want to prove that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Another approach: let $(x_n) \notin c_0$. What do you know about the sequence ?

Comment: We have $$ f(y) = \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} \vert y_n \vert = \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} \vert y_n -x_n + x_n \vert \leq f(x) + \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} \vert x_n - y_n \vert \leq f(x) + \Vert x -y \Vert_\infty.  $$ Similarly we can show $f(y) \geq f(x) - \Vert x-y\Vert_\infty$. Thus, we get that the function is lipschitz und hence continuous.

Answer (score 3):

If $(x_n)_{n\geqslant 1}\in\ell^\infty$ and $(y_n)_{n\geqslant 1}\in\ell^\infty$, we have
$$
\limsup_{n}\left\lvert x_n\right\rvert\leqslant \limsup_{n}\left(\left\lvert x_n-y_n\right\rvert+\left\lvert y_n\right\rvert\right)
\leqslant  \limsup_{n} \left\lvert x_n-y_n\right\rvert+\limsup_{n} \left\lvert y_n\right\rvert
$$
and similarly
$$
\limsup_{n}\left\lvert y_n\right\rvert\leqslant\limsup_{n} \left\lvert x_n-y_n\right\rvert+\limsup_{n} \left\lvert x_n\right\rvert
$$
hence
$$
\left\lvert \limsup_{n}\left\lvert x_n\right\rvert-\limsup_{n}\left\lvert y_n\right\rvert \right\rvert\leqslant  \limsup_{n} \left\lvert x_n-y_n\right\rvert$$
and I let you conclude.

Comment: Thanks @Davide Girauldo.

Answer (score 0):

A direct approach: Let $x=(x_n)_n\in l^{\infty}\setminus c_0.$ Then there exists $r>0$ such that the set $S=\{n:|x_n|>r\}$ is infinite. The open ball $B(x,r/2)$ in $l^{\infty}$ is disjoint from $c_0$. Because if $(y_n)_n\in B(x,r/2)$ then the set  $T= \{n: |y_n|>r/2\}$ is infinite (because $T\supset S$), so the sequence $(y_n)_n $ cannot converge to $0.$